# Different Dll Checksum when build source code on different PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

i have an asp.net webform (C#) project but when i try to build and compile project on two pc (same source code) result binary in bin are different,

Visual Studio 2015 and same publish profile settings

how we can explain why same source code make different output binary on checksum?

also i read: 
[Repeatable builds from same C# source code on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339086/repeatable-builds-from-same-c-sharp-source-code-on-different-machines)

Comment: What part of "No" from that link don't you understand? You should never assume the same source code is going to result in exactly the same binary files. If you have a versioning problem with your team, then go fix _that_.

Comment: Is compiling the same C# program twice guaranteed to produce the same binary output?

No.

Comment: So, what is your question? Why? Then see [Why is a different dll produced after a clean build, with no code changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107196/why-is-a-different-dll-produced-after-a-clean-build-with-no-code-changes) and [Why is the binary output not equal when compiling again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927558/why-is-the-binary-output-not-equal-when-compiling-again).